# Remove route in Contiki

Tags: c, contiki, cooja, contiki-ng

I am trying to remove a route in Contiki if attack is detected. I am using `struct route_entry *e; route_remove(e);`

But I am getting the following error: `undefined reference to 'route_remove'`.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste text as text.

Comment: As for your error, where is `route_delete` defined (implemented)? Do you link with the needed source, object or library file?

Comment: I tried different things like ```route_remove(next);``` After ```next=e```. But all gave different errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`route_remove` is a Rime network stack function. By default, Contiki is built with uIP (IPv6) network stack, which does not have this function.

To remove a route when the IPv6 network stack is used, [call this function](https://contiki-ng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/uip-ds6-route_8h.html):

`void uip_ds6_route_rm (uip_ds6_route_t *route)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me. But still after removing route, other nodes are still sending DIO to it. And are adding it to neighbor cache and selecting it as parent. Is there a way to completely isolate a node?